# Selecting a value from drop down other than Select Using Chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how to select a value from drop down which comes when we click in the text box but does not comes with select syntax Using Chrome

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the relevant HTML and the code you have tried and the result.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public boolean selectDropdown(WebElement element, String itemName) {
    try {
        if (select != null) {
            List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(/*use a proper selector*/);
            for (WebElement option : options) {
                String sListBoxOption = option.getText();
                if (sSelectItem.equalsIgnoreCase(sListBoxOption)){
                    option.click();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can send the web Element and the Item in the drop-down which you have to select as parameters for this method.

Comment: Works for any browser

Comment: It is under div tag followed by UL and then followed bu li . if we select that area it will be active otherwise we dont see drop down

Comment: Give a proper identifier in findElements. Something like select.findElements(By.xpath("//div/ul/li"));